# Automatically load csv/txt file from local drive into html page as table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I found a lot of good suggestions on how to load a csv/txt file into a html page into a table, but none of the solutions are working for me.  Here is the code I am working with.  I have both files located in my C: drive and basically would like to load this csv/txt file and show it on as a table in index.html.   Thanks so much!

data.txt

```
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
value1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1
value1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });
});

function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
   \\  alert(lines);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to use `ajax request` you need to create a local server, install `xampp`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will eventually use this for work and don't think they will let me install anything.  Is there a solution I could use that doesn't use a local server?

Comment: Are you using system utilities or a specific language?

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the data.txt a bit you can just load it as another script file without need for a server.

Change `data.txt` to this

```
var data = `heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
value1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1
value1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2`
```

And load it as a javascript file **before** your actual script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.txt"></script>
```

Then you can use the variable `data` which holds your file content without any ajax call.

Comment: The OP wants to access the file on the local drive. Won't the `src="data.txt"` look for that file on the server? Also, I think you intended `type="text/javascript"` (not 'src').

Comment: OP wrote that both files are stored locally, so the HTML is not placed at a server. Thx for correction.

Comment: That is correct. The csv file will automatically update a couple times a day, which is why I need to load the csv file on load.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access local files with JS. That would be serious security vulnerability, because you could send a malicious webpage to a user, which would download their files and send them to someone. As *midrizi* mentioned in the comments, you'll need a server to download files from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can retrieve a local file if you don't serve it, as pointed out in the comments to your question.

There are approaches you can take to that, though. If you can't serve it by any means, you could create a [**GitHub repo**](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/create-a-repo) and upload your file there. Then you can use the **link to your raw file**:

[image]

And you can also take steps to automate that, but it should be easy enough committing your file locally whenever you update it and push it to GitHub. Just in case you're not familiar with Git and GitHub, [here's a handy ref](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners).

**A word of caution:** unless you have total control over the characters that you include in your CSV, parsing them by naively splitting commas like that might result in ugly stuff if the values within contain commas themselves. Some CSV files also come with extra stuff in the beginning of the file (like the `sep` indicator in the first row, which defines what character to interpret as separator). **You may completely ignore these warnings if you're producing the CSV yourself.**

Also I noticed your function does not take care of building the actual table, so I changed it so it does. I also used [**Fetch API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to retrieve the data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function processData(csv) {

      let data = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/).map(v => v.split(','));

      let headers = data.shift();

      let table = document.createElement('table');

      let thead = document.createElement('thead');
      table.appendChild(thead);

      thead.innerHTML = '<tr><th>' + headers.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';

      let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
      table.appendChild(tbody);

      for (let row of data) {
        tbody.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + row.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
      }

      document.body.appendChild(table);

    }

    // I uploaded the CSV to a personal repo for this example,
    // but you CAN use a local file as long as you *serve* it
    fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gyohza/test/master/so/data.txt")
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => processData(text));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can't automatically read a local file into the browser.

But you can prompt the user to select a file, using the `<input type="file">` element.

Once a file has been selected via that input, it can be read via JavaScript.

```
<label for="file">Select a Text File:</label><br />
<input id="file" type="file" /><br/>
<button onclick="readFile()">Read File</button><br/>
```

```js
  let input = document.getElementById('file');
  let contents = document.getElementById('contents');

  function readFile () {
    let file = input.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
      console.log('reader.onload');
      contents.innerHTML = String(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Terry.  The preferred method would be to have it automatically get loaded instead of a user loading it.

Comment: @RickD I don't think you'll ever find a way to load a local file without user assistance. Browser security makes that just about impossible.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61705225/20924828
the security flaw is running the web server to access local files on the local machine. A web server is, by definition, an application that allows reading the contents of the folder to which the server is assigned. Java scripts perform actions on the client computer by downloading information from the network from a web server and present the retrieved information in a way that is understandable to the user. If I cannot use local files to interact with the website without an Internet connection, this is a security risk. Running a web server on a local machine to access local files makes these files available to everyone on the network through this running server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).