# How to give a file path as a function parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I want to convert a csv file that is stored in my project folder to an array in javascript. I have this function:

```
function csvToArray (csv) {
    rows = csv.split("\n");

    return rows.map(function (row) {
        return row.split(",");
    });
};

var csv = "the,quick,brown,fox\n" +
          "jumps,over,the,lazy,dog";

var array = csvToArray(csv);
```

My question is when i call:

```
var array = csvToArray(csv);
```

How to make that "csv" parameter to be the path of my file that is in my project folder?
For ex: cootest.csv , how do i give that file as parameter?

Comment: Hello , first tell me where do this function run , in the web browser of clients ?? and the file is in the server ?

Comment: You can simply pass it as a string

Comment: Hi, I have everything local on my pc, in the "Project" folder i have csv2array.js and cootest.csv there. And I run csv2array.js with node on my local pc in command line. How do I call it something like that "csvToArray(param) where param=the csv i have on the folder"?

Comment: How I can pass it as a string? Can you show me?

Comment: You'll need to open the file. If you are using a web browser, you can use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61705781/3113485

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

`var array = csvToArray("c:/path/to/project/cootest.csv");`

Comment: if I call it like that :var array = csvToArray("C:/Users/Catalin/Desktop/PC/Google HeatMap/cootest.csv"); I get [ [ 'C:/Users/Catalin/Desktop/PC/Google HeatMap/cootest.csv' ] ] as output, insted of lat,lng
45.652309,25.610274
49.16149,27.58405

Comment: I see. You need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader. The issue it will not load data from local desk. If you use node.js or run a local server then you can load a local file from a JS file.